# How do I get notified of a BuildDestroyedEvent

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

## Background:

I have a on premise TFS 2015 Update 1 server. In the new TFS build style builds drops done via a network share [are not deleted when the build is deleted](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10405782-retention-policies-in-tfs-2015-build-should-delete) from expiring retention policies. Our setup can not use server based drops and we must use network share drops.

As a work around I am attempting to write a service that will be notified when a build expires and is deleted and it can then delete the associated network share for me.

## Issue:

I discovered the [.NET TFS client libraries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet), in the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) NuGet package there is a `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.Events.BuildDestroyedEvent` class which looks exactly like what I need. However I can not figure out how to "subscribe" to that event.

I found [a good tutorial](https://roadtoalm.com/2012/03/29/create-tfs-event-subscription-programmatically-with-tfs-api/) using the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient) API which shows a subscription to a `WorkItemChangedEvent` with a web callback. However when I tried to a `BuildDestroyedEvent` I get a error.

```
const string collectionUri = "https://tfs.example.com:8081/tfs/MyCollection";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collectionUri)))
    {
        tpc.Authenticate();
        tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();

        var eventService = tpc.GetService<IEventService>();

        DeliveryPreference del = new DeliveryPreference();
        del.Address = "http://srchamberlain.example.com/TestWebApp/api/destroyEventSink";
        del.Schedule = DeliverySchedule.Immediate;
        del.Type = DeliveryType.Soap;


        var id = eventService.SubscribeEvent("BuildDestroyedEvent", "", del);
        Console.WriteLine(id);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The error I get on the `SubscribeEvent` line is

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.TeamFoundationServiceException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=0
  EventId=3000
  HResult=-2146232832
  IsRemoteException=true
  LogException=false
  Message=Event type BuildDestroyedEvent does not exist.
  ReportException=false
  Source=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, Object[]& outputs)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.EventWebService.SubscribeEvent(String userId, String eventType, String filterExpression, DeliveryPreference preferences, String projectName)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.TeamFoundationEventService.SubscribeEvent(String eventType, String filterExpression, DeliveryPreference preferences)
       at SandboxConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Code\SandboxConsole\SandboxConsole\Program.cs:line 33
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       Actor=""
       HResult=-2146233087
       Lang=en
       Message=Event type BuildDestroyedEvent does not exist.
       Node=""
       Role=""
       InnerException:
```

## Question:

What is the correct way get a notification of the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.Events.BuildDestroyedEvent` firing?

Comment: Do you want realtime deletion of builds? If not, a daily job which just makes a call to get builds to check whether they are deleted or not, would work.

Comment: Good idea, I think I will use that as a backup plan

Answer (score 0):

1. collectionUri for VSTS is always `https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`, other format can't be recognized.
2. the tutorials are all for TFS on-premise, not VSTS. As Event Subscriptions is a server side plugin, but VSTS is hosted, it's unable to run Subscription on server side. .Net Event Subscriptions is not supported in VSTS.
3. VSTS now supports to [create a service hooks subscription](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/create-subscription), but supported events doesn't include BuildDestroyedEvent.

Supported events:

- build completed
- code pushed (for Git team projects)
- pull request create or updated (for Git team projects)
- code checked in (TFVC team projects)
- work item created, updated, deleted, restored or commented on
- message posted to a team room

So, you may take Harshil Lodhi's advice as a workaround.

Comment: For point 1, I am running TFS on-premise, I am trying to connect to a locally running TFS 2015 Update 1 (We are planning to update to Update 2 this weekend). Also, I would still like to know using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` NuGet package what is the way to "subcribe" to ***any*** of the events in the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.Events` namespace.

Comment: I think only the events which are available as part of service hooks are available to subscribe. You can go to settings in TFS web UI and service hooks tab to see the events.

Comment: What about things that are acting as plugins and not external services, don't they get more access? The "service" I am writing does not need to be a external service, I can write it as a plugin to TFS, I just can't figure out how to access the information.

Comment: Check the list with all available events at website https://nkdagility.com/tfs-event-handler-for-team-foundation-server-2010/. There is no BuildDestroyedEvent.

Comment: Then what is [this in your TypeScript SDK for TFS](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/blob/103e7cca80ae35810c0ff43caa246ed5f33df425/typings/tfs.d.ts#L439) for then?

Comment: Also, there is [this similar documentation page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/builddeletedevent) for `BuildDeletedEvent`. (However, I do admit that the page for `BuildDestroyedEvent` does return a "Page not found" error). What do I do to access these events, even from inside a TFS extension.